# What happens to the objects Instantiated by Activity when it is paused

Tags: java, android, user-interface, chat, client-side

whenever I write a Chat client in Java, I make the client class implement **runnable** and in **run()** write an infinite loop for receiving data.
Now , in android I want to do same but am facing certain issues:

1. Does thread started by activity runs when activity is paused?
2. What happens to the objects Instantiated by Activity when it is paused.
3. Is it good that the code for Sending data is still in Interface class?

Comment: 1. Thread started by activity will run as thread is a different path of execution. Looking forward for answers for 2 and 3.

Comment: 1. yes 2. nothing in particular. 3. don't understand your question, (but I'd say no, networking relatively to an Activity is generally not a good thing (though perfectly acceptable in lots of cases))

Comment: 2.`What happens to the objects Instantiated by Activity when it is paused?` as long as activity remain alive the objects remain

Comment: Don't put the infinite loop in `Activity` as these can be killed when not visible. Also if the thread is not a static class, you may provoke memory leaks Use a dedicated class for that (maybe a `Service` to increase your app scoring when Android decides which app to kill). Can you elaborate as who is `Interface class`?

Comment: @njzk2: (3) means whenever user press button to send data this Function [dataout.writeUTF( message )] runs in UI thread/no separate thread. Its bad, right. Or it is just job of JVM to send data and Function will return quickly?

Comment: It is always a bad idea to do network on the ui thread (and it is even forbidden now) However, you'd have to check the specifics of the writeUTF function to know if it is a blocking call or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does thread started by activity runs when activity is paused?

Yes, the thread will remain alive unless the `Activity` gets destroyed by the system. It can happen, for example, in case of low memory. So it's preferable to use `Service` if you implement a long-running background operation.

> What happens to the objects Instantiated by Activity when it is paused.

Objects will still be accessible when the `Activity` comes back to the foreground. However, if the `Activity` gets destroyed or recreated the objects will also be destroyed.

The third question isn't clear, I'll be happy to provide an answer when it's clarified.

Comment: (3) means whenever user press button to send data this Function [dataout.writeUTF( message )] runs in UI thread/no separate thread. Its bad, right. Or it is just job of JVM to send data and Function will return quickly?

Comment: @Prince, Yes, it's bad. You should use a separate thread for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Service object. It will still running even application is paused or sent to background.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html